# proper way to format text to insert in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, sql-insert, text-formatting

I try to insert this information in Mysql database

```
$mytext = "this is a word in french d'origine francaise";
```

Then the PHP sql code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tchapter (content) VALUES ('". $mytext ."')";
```

It will send me an error because i have a ' apostrophe character in the $mytext, in fact it will mix between the apostrophe '". $mytext ."' that exist in the $sql.

My question is what is the proper way to prepare the text to be entered in a database to prevent any type of error with the special character.

Also i should get back the text from the database as it appear before in the html page.

Comment: If you're using MySQLi or PDO and parametrized queries, [as you should be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), this becomes a non-issue.

Comment: As @JayBlanchard suggested MySQLi or PDO is a better approach. But mysql_real_escape_string would help you. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: That would be `addslashes($str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape your string using the following function, prior to inserting in the database

> mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Please don't recommend [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) functions.